# Cloudflare DNS - How to redirect all subdomains to root domain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, cloudflare

Can somebody tell me how I can redirect all subdomains to the root domain in Cloudflare DNS?

I have been looking for a day now without any luck.

I **can't** use `.htaccess` because all the subdomains doesn't resolve (They look just like a root domain that haven't propagated) and doesn't return anything, and I don't want to set up hundreds of DNS records for each possible subdomains.

I would like to set up a wildcard dns entry to redirect or at least make all subdomains reachable, so I can either do the rest via the `.htaccess`, or through DNS.

So how do I make the DNS entry for above requirements?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the support: [Does Cloudflare support wildcard DNS entries?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017421192-Cloudflare-DNS-FAQ#CloudflareDNSFAQ-DoesCloudflaresupportwildcardDNSentries)

> **Cloudflare Free, Pro and Business plan:**
>
> We do not proxy wildcard records so these subdomains will be served
>   directly without Cloudflare performance, security, or apps. The
>   wildcard domain will have no cloud (orange or grey) on the Cloudflare
>   DNS Settings page for that reason. If you are adding a `*` CNAME or A
>   Record you need to make sure the record is grey clouded in order for
>   the record to be created.
>
> To get Cloudflare protection on a wildcard subdomain (for example:
>   www), you explicitly have to define that record in your Cloudflare DNS
>   settings. First, log into your Cloudflare account and select the DNS
>   icon. In this example, you would add "www" as its own CNAME record on
>   your Cloudflare DNS Settings page and toggle the cloud to orange so
>   the Cloudflare's proxy is enabled.

Unless you are an Enterprise customer, you can't use a wildcard to redirect through Cloudflare.

Make sure the cloud logo is grey to add a wildcard record:

[image: Cloudflare DNS: CNAME * example.com]

Comment: Yeah, that was my problem, had to click the cloud thing so it turned grey.

Comment: Link changed: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017421192-Cloudflare-DNS-FAQ#CloudflareDNSFAQ-DoesCloudflaresupportwildcardDNSentries

Comment: Update: As of May 2022, CloudFlare now supports wildcarded DNS proxying on all plans including free tier: https://blog.cloudflare.com/wildcard-proxy-for-everyone/